# Resources for a topic in geometry.

Tags: contest-math, online-resources

Okay so I was going through $\textbf{Po-Shen Loh's}$ handouts and i saw this pdf called $\textbf{brutal force.}$ Well from what i understand it is basically using induction to prove geometric problems (In a video of youtube where the USA team discusses the IMO 2006 problems, Zuming mentions this technique too).

It seems really nice and interesting however i am having a really hard time trying to find the some handouts/resources that explain this topic well. Po's handout barely mentioned it and then gave questions (which i assume is because it was originally meant for MOP students who are expected to know such stuff i guess?).

So, are there any resources out there which could help me understand this seemingly beautiful but elusivr topic? Thanks a lot.

[https://www.math.cmu.edu/~ploh/docs/math/1998-brutal.pdf](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eploh/docs/math/1998-brutal.pdf)

Comment: try the site art of problem solving if you have not already. Another one called brilliant.  https://www.thriftbooks.com/a/titu-andreescu/319021/

Comment: Yeah nope couldnt find anything on those sites.

Comment: Well, faculty who get deeply involved in contest preparation materials seem to make up their own phrases; the two books I have are by Andreescu. The good news is that you are already good at searching the web. The bad news is that the specific names used by some professors for these contest matters may not be used by anyone else, or in any books; indeed, they may be very special cases of difficult theorems that you won't see for years.

Comment: Hmmm. I just added a link to the post which is the original handout. If possible could you have a look? Incase you may know what else is it called or maybe even possibly explain it if its impossible to find it anywhere else?

Comment: You could post this in the IMO/Geometry section of AOPS forums. People there are very involved in this type of maths.